# Async Programming: Core Thread vs Blocking Threads

Tags: rust, async-await

Tokio has the concept of "core thread" and "blocking thread" [https://recursion.wtf/tracing-honeycomb/tokio/index.html#:~:text=The%20core%20threads%20are%20where,block%20other%20tasks%20from%20running](https://recursion.wtf/tracing-honeycomb/tokio/index.html#:%7E:text=The%20core%20threads%20are%20where,block%20other%20tasks%20from%20running).

> The core threads are where all asynchronous code runs, and Tokio will by default spawn one for each CPU core. The blocking threads are spawned on demand, and can be used to run blocking code that would otherwise block other tasks from running.

Is this a generic concept across all async libraries (even those in different languages), or is it very specific to tokio implementation?

For example: What are the biggest conceptual differences between tokio single threaded runtime and asyncio in python?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a novel concept.

I cannot speak for Python's asyncio, but I can speak for NodeJS; it uses a primary single-threaded event queue for executing almost everything you write, but it has additional "worker" threads that NodeJS uses internally for I/O and CPU-intensive tasks which can also be leveraged for that purpose yourself. See the guide [Don't Block the Event Loop (or the Worker Pool)](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop).

You can also see this pattern when using `async`/`await` in C#; any CPU-bound code should not be ran directly in an `async` function, but rather should be executed in the background on another thread via `Task.Run()`. See [Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios) by Microsoft.

The goal is always the same: to always allow small tasks to run so the program remains responsive.